# Calling data from another file - MIPS

Tags: mips

A relatively simple question but how do I call data from another file?

For example in C:

```
#include "secondfile.h"
```

This would allow me to access the information in that file but how would I do that in MIPS?

Comment: I assume that _"MIPS"_ here means MIPS assembly language. But you haven't mentioned which specific tools you're using.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I mean MIPS assembly language, what do you mean by tools?

Comment: You're using something to assemble and run your code. You haven't mentioned what that something is.

Comment: @Michael I'm using gedit to write the code and do you mean spim by running it?

Comment: Just load each assembly file one after the other. If the simulator asks you if you want to reinitialize, answer no.

Comment: @Michael Like in the terminal?

Comment: I figured you were using one of the GUI versions of SPIM (QtSpim or PcSpim). If you're invoking SPIM via the command line then I don't know.